# Using "basically" in an interview

Tags: sentence

Can I use word *basically* in an interview?

For example

> I *basically* belong to X but I am working at Y from last 10 years.

Or can I use

> I belong to X and I am working at Y from last 10 years.

Comment: **for** the last ten years.

Comment: @CodeForFuture: If you don't want your command of English to let you down at the interview, you should be far more concerned about what you've written above after the word *"but"*, which is ungrammatical and completely unnatural to a native speaker. Just forget about whether your use of *"basically"* might be considered "slangy" by some people, and change the "rider" to something like *"but I **have been working** at Y **for the** last 10 years"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the comment.FYI I am not a native english speaker. And I must admit that I don't have a good english knowledge also. But I am here to improve my english speaking skills.

Comment: @CodeForFuture: Haha - as my comment implies, it's really obvious you're not a native speaker! But as StoneyB says in his answer, you're certainly right to suspect some people might find this use of "basically" a bit irritating, like. Just as ***many*** people would find my use of "like" there irritating. Anyway - welcome to ELU, but I'd advise you to stick mainly to *asking* questions (and posting comments) rather than *answering* them, unless you're ***very*** sure of what you're saying.

Comment: got u @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. It looks like you've picked up on the fact that "basically" has become a sort of generic synonym for many more specific terms and constructions—on the one hand,  "formally", "officially", "technically", "according to the organization chart", even "really", and on the other, "simply", "in short", "fundamentally", "at bottom", "in the most general terms", and so forth.

It's probably OK to use "basically" this loosely in an oral interview, but in writing—in your resumé, for instance—it's better to describe your situation with greater precision:

> I am formally employed as a Senior Developer in the X division, but for the last ten years I have worked with the cross-divisional Y team.

Answer (score 3):

The problem, and it’s a small one, with *basically*, *essentially*, and to a certain extent *actually* is that they are hedge words. They can convey a little undertone, one or more of:

- I need a minute to think so I am adding a filler word (this can be taken by some people as a sign of lying)
- I am going to tell you something other than what I wrote on my resume and then say that there's really no difference
- I am going to wildly oversimplify something to make myself look better (*I basically ran the entire operation and my boss just played solitaire all day*)
- I don't think you can understand the real situation so I’m going to tell you the simplified version (this is the part some people think is patronizing)

None of these are very nice. If I were to tell you to avoid it though, it would be mild advice. If I thought it was a verbal tic of yours, being added to every sentence whether it was needed or not, I would suggest backing off on it a bit. In your example you want to explain that there is a “it looks like *this* but in reality it’s more *that*” situation and *basically* wouldn't be wrong there. It wouldn’t be my first choice; I would probably avoid adjectives (especially ones that might be misinterpreted) and say “I worked for X and was assigned to Y” in that case.

Answer (score 0):

"Basically" word can be used selectively. Ideally, when comparison is in question,
in order to differentiate between two or more things/items/issues, this word usage will be appropriate and fitting. It is desirable that we use fitting words during the interview.

Answer (score -1):

It’s better to say the second sentence as using the word *basically* can sometimes seem patronising/rude.

It isn’t the end of the world if you use the word *basically* but try to avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

I personally see nothing wrong with *basically* and disagree that it sounds patronising/rude.

I would, however, say

> I basically belong to X but I *have been* working at Y *for the* last 10 years.

Comment: Just curious; why the downvote?  I am active on other S.E sites and extremely rarely downvote - and never without stating a reason. I have always thought that the system ought to reuire a comment in order to downvote (ymmv). In this case I am merely cusious as to why.